# Position a Form at the bottom left corner of another form

Tags: c#

i need some help regarding form locations and/or start positions.

So i have one form, which is the Main one and i have a second form. The second form i want to pop up in the bottom left corner of the main form, if i press a button in the main form.

I searched forever on google and i cant find any solution...

My current code for the second form looks like that:

```
Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.Location = new Point(0,
                                        workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
```

And the problem with this code is, that it places the form in the bottom left corner of the screen.

I would be very relieved if someone could help me.

Greetings

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?  I am guessing WinForms.  Have you tried getting the location of the main form and computing your coordinates from that. The reason you are having the form show up in the bottom left corner of the screen is that you are getting the working area of the entire screen and setting your location based on that. Get the location of the main form, and compute your location from the main form.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction (assuming this is WinForms). It is not an exact duplicate of your issue, but it should give you a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4608604/416574

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is pretty much what you need:

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
f.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y + this.Height);
f.Show();
```

This will place your Form2 instance underneath your initial form.

If you want to place your 2nd form in the bottom left hand corner of your main form so it is overlapping then you'd change the `f.Location` line for this:

```
f.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y + this.Height - f.Height);
```

It gets the Y location of the current form, adds on it's height to get the bottom corner then subtracts the height of your new form so that it should sit overlapping the bottom corner of your main form.